# How to instantiate multiple instances of the same resource using Hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

Using Hiera, is it possible to instantiate two classes with different properties?

I know I can do add to my node declaration:

```
user{'francois':
  uid => 1000,
  # ...
}

user{'julien':
  uid => 1001,
  # ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this from Hiera?

Comment: For **classes**, this is not possible, with or without Hiera. For **resources** (as in your example with users), it is quite simple, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use hashes for your data and use `create_resources` to instantiate.

The [Puppet documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources) has an example for users. The StackOverflow question
[Puppet hiera and create_resource issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911151/puppet-hiera-and-create-resource-issue) covers basically the same problem.