# Get value from hiera hash in Puppet

Tags: puppet, samba, hiera

I have this structure in my hiera file that create some rules in my smb.conf.

```
samba::shares:
  PDF:
    - comment = "PDF"
    - path = /home/smb/pdf
    - browseable = yes
    - hide dot files = yes
    - read only = no
    - public = yes
    - writable = yes
    - create mode = 0775
    - printable = no
  Partage:
   - comment= "Partage"
   - path = /home/smb/Partage
   - browseable = yes
   - hide dot files = yes
   - read only = no
   - public = yes
   - writable = yes
   - create mode = 0775
   - printable = no
```

I want to access the path of each share for create automatically the folder with the right persmissions.

I tried many solutions with hiera_hash() but I can not find the right setting. :

```
define create_folder{
  # I want to loop on PDF, Partage, etc. and extract path 
  # for each one (/home/smb/pdf, /home/smb/Partage, etc.).
  $path = hiera_hash('path') 

  file{"$path":
    path => $path,
    ensure => diretory,
    owner => "smb",
    group => "smb",
    require => File["/home/smb/"],
    mode => '775',
  }
}
```

Can you help me please ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application for the [`create_resources`](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources) method.

In your case, you would not fetch the hash from inside the resource, but from outside:

```
# puppet/site.pp
create_resources(create_folder, hiera_hash('samba::shares', {}))

# puppet/modules/...
define create_folder(
  $comment,
  $path,
  $browseable,
  $hide_dot_files,
  $read_only,
  $public,
  $writable,
  $create mode,
  $printable,
){
  file{"$path":
    path => $path,
    ensure => diretory,
    owner => "smb",
    group => "smb",
    require => File["/home/smb/"],
    mode => '775',
  }
}
```

The 2<sup>nd</sup> argument to `hiera_hash` is a default value. I prefer to always keep an empty Hash there in order to be able to load the resource on all machines, even if only certain machines have the values defined.

Comment: Note that the keys in your YAML files would have to be renamed: Puppet won't like keys with spaces in them. I replaced spaces with underscores there.

Comment: See [How to instantiate multiple instances of the same resource using Hiera](https://serverfault.com/questions/648584/how-to-instantiate-multiple-instances-of-the-same-resource-using-hiera/648613#648613) for my own question on the subject, and [Puppet hiera and create_resource issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911151/puppet-hiera-and-create-resource-issue) for the definitive answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have found another solution but I keep yours for future developments. ;) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,
I add one script who's run everty time puppet run :

```
#!/bin/bash
folders=($(cat /etc/samba/smb.conf | grep path | cut -d" "  -f3))

for folder in "${folders[@]}" ; do
  if [ ! -d "$folder" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$dossier"
    chown -R smb:smb "$folder"
    chmod -R 775 "$folder"
  fi
done
```

Regards.